# How to inject into the same class from different Dagger2 components?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Let's say I have multiple activities and every activity contains separate Dagger2 component. So `FooActivity` has `FooComponent` and `BarActivity` has `BarComponent`. Also I have some viewgroup let's say `BazViewGroup` that can be used in both activities and must receive some dependencies through dagger graph. What is best way to inject dependencies into instance of this viewgroup since we don't know in advance in what activity it belongs?

Right now I have the following setup:

1. Every activity exposes method `getComponent()` which returns component contained in this activity
2. Every component extends interface like

   ```
   public interface CanInjectIntoBazViewGroup {
       void inject(BazViewGroup viewgroup);
   }
   ```
3. Inside BazViewGroup constuctor I get reference to activity get component from it, cast it to `CanInjectIntoBazViewGroup` and call `inject` method.

Is there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for Dagger 2 is not to abuse it (like any other thing).

So, if you already have components for your `Activities`, and you have a reference to `BazViewGroup` in both `Activities`, then I don't see any reason to use Dagger 2 in order to perform DI into this `BazViewGroup`.

There are two cases.

**ViewGroup is declared in XML:**

If you declare `BazViewGroup` in XML and let Android inflate it for you, then you can perform a "method DI" - define methods like `setXYZ()` on this object and pass `XYZ` from your `Activities` after view hierarchy inflated.

**You create the ViewGroup programmatically:**

If you are instantiating the `ViewGroup` programmatically, then you can add its dependencies as constructor parameters.

Both approaches are not so clean because they create some coupling between `Activity` and internals of `ViewGroup`, but it is much better than coupling `ViewGroup` to Dagger framework.

The cleaner way is to remove these dependencies from `ViewGroup`. I guess you need them in order to perform some actions on user interaction, or to query for data, right? Why don't create callback interface and delegate all these actions to the enclosing `Activity`? This way, if you refactor your business logic one day, your custom `Views` won't be affected.